# C++ run function in given date and time

Tags: c++, boost, time, scheduler

I have written some service using C++, QT and boost.

I need some function run in given time (for maintance purposes).

The only method I have worked as expected is to pool current time in thread.

I've try to use boost method:

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer (io_service);
boost::gregorian::date day = boost::gregorian::day_clock::local_day();
boost::posix_time::time_duration time = boost::posix_time::duration_from_string(START_TIME);
boost::posix_time::ptime expirationtime ( day, time );
timer.expires_at (expirationtime);
timer.async_wait (boost::bind(func, param1, param2));
io_service.run();
```

This works for today if I don't change system time. But if I try to set it for tommorow (or any other day in future), for example, and change system time to test it - it doesn't fire (it's count miliseconds after async_wait call?)

Is there any other methods beside time pooling to start task in given day and time (NOT time interval)?

Comment: why not do it from the operating system? If you're in the unix/linux world you can use `cron` to schedule a job - see e.g. http://aplawrence.com/BDD/bbcronbasics.html There should be some way to do it in windows too.

Comment: @Marinos K, 1. This service is multi-platform. 2. Function use a lot of special functions and classes from service code, so it can't be simply run as external script.

Comment: in that case the only obvious solution to me would be to regularly query the time from the system (either using some external command - e.g. `date` in POSIX, or an appropriate function). This probably means that you'll have to rely on platform-dependent headers but it wouldn't be much of a work to do.

Comment: @Marinos K, as I wrote before - it's work now in this way - I pooling the current time in thread. I just wonder if there any other more "beautiful" method.

Comment: While not a proper solution I think it's much better to use some short-interval timer and poll time when it fires instead of polling time in a thread. Btw, did you try QTimer?

Comment: @ixSci, shure I use interval for polling time. And yes, I've tried QTimer, for my purposes I can use only intervals from it's functional, because It's also can't fire event with given time, only with intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of periodic polling, you can use `std::this_thread::sleep_until`.

According to the [description on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) this will take subsequent clock adjustments into account:

> Blocks the execution of the current thread until specified sleep_time has been reached.
>
> The clock tied to `sleep_time` is used, which means that adjustments of the clock are taken into account. Thus, the duration of the block might, but might not, be less or more than `sleep_time - Clock::now()` at the time of the call, depending on the direction of the adjustment. The function also may block for longer than until after `sleep_time` has been reached due to scheduling or resource contention delays.

However, this is new as of C++11.  If your compiler doesn't support that, you may need to poll.  Unless there is other library support depending on your OS.  Also, `sleep_until` *might* be using polling internally (or it is cleverly waking up and reconfiguring if the clock changes).

As mentioned in comments, your problem is more commonly solved externally (invoking your process on schedule) via `cron` on Unix-style systems (including Mac OS X), or Task Scheduler on Windows.  Such external invocations are more robust when it comes to potential failures of your task.